# How to read whole chapter from epub files?

Tags: android, epub

I want to make **epub reader** app.Now i am getting only chapter name in the file but how to get whole data in the chapter.

Comment: Explain what you you done till now... what are you using to read the epub contents?

Comment: I am using epublib library..I am getting title,author name and all the chapter name but i am not getting text inside the chapter.I dont know how to get it.

Comment: @Umesh i am also reading epub file but in some long file it's give me error of outOfMemory if you face and solve that issue then please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think I have already posted this out before.
Using nl.siegmann.epublib which you can google.
In my code I will show you how I did it as you look at Book class which shows how the the epub works.
Using Spine on book class I get the maximum spine of the book which means the entire book.
I then convert it to string.

Here is my code on how I did it.

```
public String getEntireBook()
    {
        String line, linez = null;
        Spine spine = amBook().getSpine();
        Resource res;
        List<SpineReference> spineList = spine.getSpineReferences() ;

        int count = spineList.size();
        int start = 0;

        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = start; count > i; i = i +1) {
            res = spine.getResource(i);

                try {
                    InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    try {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            linez =   string.append(line + "\n").toString();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        return linez;
    }
```

Comment: @sesdfgfgd can you tell me what is spine becuase it's give me error i also face this same problem so if you can help me.

Comment: Read the documents at http://www.siegmann.nl/static/epublib/apidocs/ . To answer your question what spine is "Spine: these are the Resources to be shown when a user reads the book from start to finish." You can start looking at book class as it shows the hierarchy and how it works. Good luck.